# Hashicorp Vault client best practise

Tags: security, authentication, hashicorp-vault

I have an application using Hashicorp Vault to store a username and password secret. The application is deployed to a cloud hosting platform and passed a token as an environment variable. On application start the secret is read from vault using the token and used to open a session to a remote service. The application and session to the remote service are long lived. If all goes well the application rarely restarts and therefore rarely reads from vault. When the application does restart the token will likely have expired resulting in failure.

Is there any best practice guidance for how clients should use vault? The token lifetime could be extended but the longer the lifetime the more compromised the security. The application could reestablish the session with the remote service every time it is needed but this would be inefficient. Is there another alternative I’m not considering? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [App Roles](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle.html) instead of passing in a plain token. In this, you bake a role id into your app, and then deploy a secret id for that role in your environment variable.

Your app can then combine these to get a real token from Vault on startup, and periodically renew that token as it is running.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Comment: // , Client Certificate authentication might work well, too.

Comment: I'm learning about Vault so maybe I don't understand completely. But isn't still a security risk that someone can still read both `role-id and secret id` in this case and generate tokens? I'm still looking for some kind of solution where you can create the token in memory and make the previous token invalid. So, for eg. create a token by reading some ENV variable and then pass it to the app(using some CI tool maybe) and then the app can create a new token and revoke the previous one. So, even if you know the ENV variable it doesn't matter.

Comment: Update found this for above: https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/secrets-management/sm-cubbyhole